# Create a trie in perl

Tags: perl, trie

Objective is to create a trie data structure. I had seen [`Tree::Trie`](http://search.cpan.org/~avif/Tree-Trie-1.5/Trie.pm) and used it. It converts data into trie structure only after the file(database) is read. So this will make processing slow as each time a lookup is needed entire data is converted into trie.

Is there a way where I can create a trie for one time and use it the trie structure for lookups.

Comment: If you look at the [sources](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/AVIF/Tree-Trie-1.5/Trie.pm) of `Tree::Trie`, you'll see that the data are added to the trie as soon as you `add` them (you can see `add` calling `_add_internal`). And the documentation states as much.

Answer (score 5):

If you look again at the synopsis in the `Tree::Trie` documentation that you linked to, you will see that the trie is only created once (`my($trie) = new Tree::Trie;` - although this should be written as `my $trie = Tree::Trie->new;` rather than using indirect object notation) and data is only added to it once (`$trie->add(...);`), and then the trie is used for multiple lookups (`my(@all) = $trie->lookup("");` and `my(@ms)  = $trie->lookup("m");`).

The way to create the trie once and then use it for lookups, then, is to simply keep the `$trie` variable around (in scope) and use it for all your lookups instead of creating new `Tree::Trie` instances each time.

If this answer isn't useful to you, please update your question to include a small, self-contained, runnable example program showing how you're using `Tree::Trie` and we can show you how to modify it so that the trie only gets built once.

Comment: I want the database to be stored in trie format. Something like the database will be converted to trie structure which means database might be similar to a object file. In simple words is there a way where I can compile the database so that a trie structureed object file is generated which can be used for lookup.